# SQL to select all entries on most recent date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in a postgres db:

```
create table aerialpic(
    id varchar(36) not null,
    version integer default 1 not null,
    filename varchar not null,
    location varchar not null,
    takenat bigint);
```

with some test data:

```
INSERT INTO public.aerialpic (id, version, filename, location, takenat) VALUES ('f98c03b2-126d-4c0c-af84-645537a72f60', 1, 'South Passage Bar 1', 'South Passage', 1531720800000);
INSERT INTO public.aerialpic (id, version, filename, location, takenat) VALUES ('74b78410-e80c-42cd-a26d-321e9b121da3', 1, 'Jumpinpin Bar 1', 'Jumpinpin Bar', 1531721700000);
INSERT INTO public.aerialpic (id, version, filename, location, takenat) VALUES ('b73cc37c-cb33-473e-a421-885566b4a2f1', 1, 'Wide Bay Bar3 1', 'Wide Bay Bar', 1531630800000);
INSERT INTO public.aerialpic (id, version, filename, location, takenat) VALUES ('b73cc37c-cb33-473e-a421-885566b4a2f2', 1, 'Wide Bay Bar3 2', 'Wide Bay Bar', 1531631800000);
INSERT INTO public.aerialpic (id, version, filename, location, takenat) VALUES ('b73cc37c-cb33-473e-a421-885566b4a2f3', 1, 'Wide Bay Bar3 3', 'Wide Bay Bar', 1530631800000);
INSERT INTO public.aerialpic (id, version, filename, location, takenat) VALUES ('f98c03b2-126d-4c0c-af84-645537a72f61', 1, 'South Passage Bar 2', 'South Passage', 1530720800000);
```

I did have the following SQL to get for each unique `location` the most recent entry:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() 
    over (partition by location order by takenat desc) as row_number
    from aerialpic
) as rows
where row_number = 1
```

This worked well but now I need to change it to also return for each unique `location` the most recent entry **plus** any other entry for that location that is on the same day as the most recent one.

The result using the test data would return the rows containing `filename` of:

```
South Passage Bar 1
Jumpinpin Bar 1
Wide Bay Bar3 1
Wide Bay Bar3 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need `rank()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             rank() over (partition by location order by takenat desc) as row_number
      from aerialpic a
     ) a
where row_number = 1;
```

If `takenat` represents a millisecond Unix timestamp, then some arithmetic is needed as well:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             rank() over (partition by location order by floor(takenat / (24*60*60*1000)) desc) as row_number
      from aerialpic a
     ) a
where row_number = 1;
```